# TFLite model can not be loaded by using C_api.h

Tags: c++, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite, flatbuffers

I am trying to deploy a TFLite model in my c++ pipeline. But when I use functions in c_api.h of tflite. It can not load model tflite model correctly.

The 1st image is the script I convert to freeze graph(.pb file)

[image]

The second image is script I convert to tflite.[image]

The third image is the c code to load model by using c_api.h.[image]

The error I got is "ERROR: The model is not a valid Flatbuffer file"
Many thanks to who can help me out!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code of using the TFLite C API is correct. Seems like there is a bug in the model you are feeding to it.
Can you open that model using netron or the [visualize tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/faq#how_do_i_inspect_a_tflite_file)?

Another tip is you can try to run that model using the benchmarking tool: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark. If it run successfully, then it is likely that your model is OK.